# strpos function error. I'm trying to parse MRZ from string

Tags: php, laravel

```
if ( strpos( '<' , '<<<8' ) )
     {
         echo "found";
     }
```

above code return false.I'm trying to read MRZ characters from string.

Comment: You need to check `strpos('<' , '<<<8')) !== false` - the function returns the first index, which for you is `0`, so you get `if (0)`, which is a falsy statement.

Comment: @Qirel write that as an answer instead of a comment, it seems like the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you for response @Qirel .
I have already tried this but still it is not working.

Comment: @mybytecode That's because the order of parameters is haystack, then needle. https://3v4l.org/0f8dD (string to look in, string to look for).